# PHP Displaying CSV file, Skip the first row

Tags: php, csv, foreach, console, gzip

I'm trying to display the CSV file data, which is inside of the gz file.

My code is:

```
    $file = file("compress.zlib://".$filePath);

     foreach($file as $line){
    list($lid,$lname,$lrevenue,$ctr) = explode(",", $line);

     print $lid ." | ".  $lname ." | ". $lrevenue ." | ". $ctr . "\n";

     }
```

This code works but I don't know how to skip displaying the first row from it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = file("compress.zlib://".$filePath);

unset($file[0]);

foreach($file as $line){

    list($lid,$lname,$lrevenue,$ctr) = explode(",", $line);
    print $lid ." | ".  $lname ." | ". $lrevenue ." | ". $ctr . "\n";    
}
```

Comment: If it helped. Please mark it as the correct solution and up vote it so others with your problem know. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = file("compress.zlib://".$filePath);

$i=0;
foreach($file as $line){

    if($i == 0) continue;
    list($lid,$lname,$lrevenue,$ctr) = explode(",", $line);
    print $lid ." | ".  $lname ." | ". $lrevenue ." | ". $ctr . "\n";

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!